# Mongoose - How to validate model when updating?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, model

I have the following model. When I try to create with wrong information it doesn't allow but if I try to edit the information allows it. How can I prevent that?

```js
var userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
    },
    match: /[0-9]{8}/,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  histórico: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Request",
    },
  ],
  role: { type: String },

  estado: { type: String, enum: ["Infetado", "Suspeito", "Curado"] },

});

userController.updateUserPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const oldUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userId, {
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  //nao permitir password vazia
  const newUser = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
  res.send({
    old: oldUser,
    new: newUser,
  });
};

userController.updateUserState = async (req, res) => {
  const oldUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userId, {
    estado: req.body.estado,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updateValidators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators) are off by default, you need to specify `runValidators: true` option in the update operation.

```js
userController.updateUserPassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const oldUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.userId,
      {
        password: req.body.password,
      },
      {
        runValidators: true,
      }
    );

    //nao permitir password vazia
    const newUser = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    res.send({
      old: oldUser,
      new: newUser,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong.');
  }
};
```

Comment: where do I activate it?

Comment: I´ve done it and now whenever I try to update to an invalid password postman only stays at "sending request". Is that suppose to happen?

Comment: @FábioPires can you add a try catch block as I did in the updated answer, and check the api console for error?

Comment: It worked .Dumb question, instead of sending that something went wrong wouldn´t be better to send that the password is invalid or should I avoid to show the user what the error was?

Comment: @FábioPires yes it would be better if it is validation error, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056021/improve-mongoose-validation-error-handling/61056403#61056403)